# estaba/estuve + haciendo algo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos

Sé qué signica "estoy/esta haciendo" algo. Tambien sé qué signica "estaba" y "estuve/estuvo".

Pero, qual es la diferencia entre "estaba nadando" y "estuve/estuvo nadando"?

Comment: "Estaba nadando" sets the scene for the next part of the narration; "Estuve nadando" is complete by itself (and is not as common).

Comment: Ayudaría si en tu perfil conocieramos tu idioma nativo, así te podríamos dar ejemplos de expresiones equivalentes.

Comment: @DGaleano sabes todas las idiomas en el mundo para poder darme xpresiones equivalentes?

Comment: Entre los miembros de la comunidad no sabemos todos pero si los suficientes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La diferencia entre (1) "estaba nadando" y (2) "estuvo nadando" es sutil porque ambos son tiempos continuos.

(1) se suele usar con adverbiales antecedidos por "cuando" para introducir una acción puntual en el pasado, mientras que la acción expresada por "estaba + V-ando/endo" proporciona la circunstancia o el marco de la anterior:

- **Estaba nadando** cuando de repente **vio** un tiburón. (Tal vez haya continuado nadando.)

(2) también indica continuidad pero hasta un cierto momento (en que se interrumpió la acción) y puede venir acompañado por un adverbial introducido por "hasta":

- **Estuvo nadando** dos horas hasta que se acalambró. (Luego dejó de nadar.)

También podemos decir:

- **Nadó** dos horas hasta que se acalambró. (En este caso se pierde la idea de progresión de la acción, la que se visualiza como un proceso completo, de inicio a fin.)

Comment: por qué respondiste en Ingles? Apenas logré entenderlo.

Comment: @roman-voran Perdón, no cambié el chip. Ahora te lo traduzco.